# EditText.requestFocus() returns true but doesn't really give focus to the view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I have an `EditText` in expandable action view in Toolbar. When I expand the action, the `EditText` is shown and I want it to get focus. To achieve that I do following:

`action_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/connections_find_people_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/connections_find_people_edit"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_connection, menu);
    mAddMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add);

    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(mAddMenuItem, R.layout.action_layout);
    mSearchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mAddMenuItem);

    mSearchEditText = (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.connections_find_people_edit);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(mAddMenuItem, mOnSearchExpandListener);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

private final OnSearchExpandListener mOnSearchExpandListener = new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener {
        mSearchEditText.requestFocus();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(final MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, this does not work. After tapping the action in toolbar, the view expands, `mSearchEditText` is shown, but doesn't get focus.

More specifically (and weirdly), `mSearchEditText.requestFocus();` **returns true**, but software keyboard is still not shown and there is no cursor in `mSearchEditText`.

Showing software keyboard is not a big deal, there are ways to force it, but even when I show the keyboard, **typing doesn't insert any text** into `mSearchEditText`. It's only after I tap on `mSearchEditText` when cursor appears and I can type some text in it.

---

What I've tried:

- Setting `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` both in XML and programatically and both in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and when the action view is expanded
- Clearing focus before requesting it like `mSearchEditText.clearFocus()`
- Delaying `requestFocus()` after the view expands

It's really weird, because following

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(final MenuItem item) {
    mSearchEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mSearchEditText.setFocusable(true);
    mSearchView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mSearchEditText.requestFocus()) {
                KeyboardUtils.showSoftKeyboard(ConnectionsFragment.this);
            }
        }
    }, 300);
    return true;
}
```

shows the keyboard, which should mean `mSearchEditText` has focus, but typing doesn't enter any text. (Again, when I tap on the EditText, cursor appears and everything works fine).

Comment: Try changing relative layout android:layout_width to match_parent. Set some hint text to editext to see the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaand as it happens sometimes, soon after posting the question I found the answer myself.

Instead of getting reference to the `EditText` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` I had to use the `MenuItem` passed to `onMenuItemActionExpand()` and get the reference there.

So this now works for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(final MenuItem item) {
    final View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    final View edit = actionView.findViewById(R.id.connections_find_people_edit);
    if(edit.requestFocus()) {
        KeyboardUtils.showSoftKeyboard(ConnectionsFragment.this);
    }
    return true;
}
```